# My print function syntax is causing an error in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I have a list of lists with tuples. I want to get the length of a tuple using:

```
item1=(4, 8, 16, 30)
list6=[[(4, 8, 16, 29)], [(4, 8, 16, 30)], [(4, 8, 16, 32)]]
print("list6.index((4, 8, 16, 29)):",list6.index([item1]))
print("len(list6[1]):"), len(list6[1])

Output:    
list6.index((4, 8, 16, 29)): 1
len(list6[1]):
```

There is no value for len(list6[1]). Can someone show me the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The print statement correctly outputs "1".

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Statement prints `1`

Comment: The odd thing is the program exits correctly: "Process finished with exit code 0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine in Python 2. If you are using Python 3, there is an issue with last line, because `print` is a function. So, because of where you've put the close parenthesis, only the first part is actually passed to `print`. Try this instead

```
print("len(list6[1]):", len(list6[1]))
```

Comment: Rather shocking on my part. I may be relying too much on the editor to pick up the syntax errors. I am using Python 3. Great, thank you.